# Random username generator using dictionary instead of random character string

Tags: php, dictionary, random

I've found several attempts at creating random username generators but they really just consist of a set of random characters appended to a string. This is sufficient for usage but `it really just looks awkward as it doesn't seem very human-like instead of just a set of random characters`.

**Is there a php library that handles username generating from a dictionary instead of a random character generating function**

The closest I've found is here: [mudnames](https://github.com/xrogaan/phpMudnames) but the problem is the dictionary isn't in english.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to ask for solutions, giving a particular set of guidelines, not just libraries, because that's off-topic here.

Comment: You can try to ask this question on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always roll your own:

```
function get_random_username(array $dictionary, $separator = '-', $min = 2, $max = 3) {
    return implode(
        $separator,
        array_map(
            function ($key) use ($dictionary) {
                return trim($dictionary[$key]);
            },
            array_rand($dictionary, rand($min, $max))
        )
    );
}
```

Here are three usage examples. The first uses a static array as a word source, the second uses the [`fzaninotto Faker`](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) library, and the last uses the GNU/Linux dictionary as a word source:

```
var_dump(
    get_random_username( 
        array ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux')
    ),
    get_random_username( 
        \Faker\Factory::create()->unique()->words(1000)
    ),
    get_random_username(
        file('/usr/share/dict/words')
    )
);
```

Example run:

```
$ php gen.php
string(12) "bar-foo-quux"
string(11) "porro-magni"
string(11) "razor-edged"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own.
First: Record some names in a mysql database with an id.
Then: In PHP, get them randomly.

For example:

mysql table

```
id -- names
2.....John
3.....Melissa
.............
999.....Saba
```

PHP CODE:

```
    <?php
$random_id= rand(1,999); //get a random id

$sql="select*from NAMES where id='$random_id'" //then get a random name with id
//Your other codes...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generate Random Usernames**

```
$a = array(
    'key' => 'word1',
    'key2' => 'word2',

);

$random_word =  $a[array_rand($array)];
```

You can also remove the word from the dictionary once it has been used in order to generate truly unique random usernames.In addition, you can append some random chars with words to make it more human-like.You can import any valid dictonary of words to PHP array to use it.Finally you can pick two random words, add some random chars and generate complex random usernames.